# Relationship between direct sum representation and quotient in Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and $H_{1}, H_{2}$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $V=H_{1}\oplus H_{2}$. Now $V/H_{1}$ is isomorphic to $H_{2}$.

If we replace the vector space $V$ by a group $G$ and consider $H_1$ ,a normal subgroup of $G$, then **under what conditions** can we say that if $G=H_{1}\oplus H_{2}$ (which is same as $G = H_1 H_2)$, for some subgroup $H_2$ in $G$, then $G/H_{1}$ is isomorphic to $H_{2}$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should maybe explain what you think $G = H_1 \oplus H_2$ means. In general, the notation $G = H_1 \times H_2$ is reserved for direct products (i.e. multiplication is coordinate-wise). It seems that you mean $G = H_1 H_2$ (the subgroup generated by products $h_1h_2$ with $h_1 \in H_1$, $h_2 \in H_2$), with $H_1 \cap H_2 = 0$, and $H_1$ normal.

Comment: It's always true that if $G \cong H_1 \times H_2$, then $G$ quotiented by the particular copy of $H_1$ coming from this isomorphism is isomorphic to $H_2$. It doesn't follow that $G$ quotiented by any subgroup isomorphic to $H_1$ will be isomorphic to $H_2$.

Comment: @Remy Yes I think $G = H_1 H_2$ is what it should be.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : If $G \cong H_1 \times H_2$, then I guess we can construct some example where not taking exact copy of $H_1$ will cause problem, but is there a better way to see this fact ?(some general result?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Lemma.** If $H_1, H_2 \subseteq G$ are two subgroups, with $H_1$ normal, such that $H_1 \cap H_2 = 0$ and $H_1 H_2 = G$, then $G/H_1 \cong H_2$.

Note that when $H_1$ is normal, the set $H_1 H_2$ is just the set of products $h_1 h_2$ with $h_1 \in H_1$ and $h_2 \in H_2$ (the statement here is that the latter subset is already a subgroup).

*Proof.* Consider the quotient map $G \to G/H_1$, and restrict it to a map $\pi \colon H_2 \to G/H_1$. Then the assumptions imply that $\pi$ is injective and surjective (think!).

Comment: Ah! That wasn't so bad after all. I guess I got mixed up in the definition of direct sum and product.

Comment: When I present it like this it doesn't look so bad, but it's good to think about what different variants you can come up with and see if they hold or not. For example, it is *not* in general true that $G \cong H_1 \times H_2$ (with coordinatewise multiplication) in this case. Try to find some examples of this.

Comment: What do you think of my answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Different proof of Remy's Lemma:

1. Observe $g \in G$ is uniquely $g=ab$ for some $(a,b) \in H_1 \times H_2$
2. Define the projection map onto $H_2$ $\phi:G \to H_2$, $\phi_2(g=ab):=b$.
3. $\phi_2$ is a surjective group homomorphism with $\ker \phi_2 = H_1$.
4. By (3), apply the 1st isomorphism theorem.

---

Edit: Proof $\phi_2$ is a group homomorphism (wow that was hard): Let $abcd \in G$ for $a,c \in H_1$ and $b,d \in H_2$. We must show $\phi_2(abcd)=\phi_2(ab)\phi_2(cd)=bd$. This is true if $abcd=ebd$ for some $e \in H_1$. Choose $e=abcb^{-1}$, which we can do because $H_1$'s normality gives us $bcb^{-1} \in H_1$.

Comment: What's a little unclear about this approach is why $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. It's fine, but you have to think.

Comment: @Remy Thanks! Edited answer to include this. Wow that was hard. I guess you were right in thinking that part is not so trivial (with trivial as synonymous to clear).